# lvalue required as left operand of asssignment

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, lvalue

I tried using a boolean expression while writing switch statements[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HKTz.png). What have I done wrong here
and what does this statement - " lvalue required as left operand of asssignment " mean ?

I was expecting both conditions to work i.e

If user types smaller case y or uppercase Y it should not be a problem.

Keep in mind I am just a beginner at C++.

Comment: Post code as text here not external images.

Comment: The error message states "... assignment..." where you know that you are writing a conditional... Take a closer look at the highlighted statement and be grateful for the compiler's very specific error description... Learn to evaluate these things for yourself, and not be dependent on others to spot typo errors... Also, be more generous with _whitespace_ and these sorts of typos will be more obvous...

Comment: The error message is saying that you can't assign `confirm` to `'Y'` because you accidentally typed `confirm = 'Y'` instead of `confirm == 'Y'`

Answer (score 2):

You 2nd condition should be `confirm=='Y'` You have `confirm='Y'` and this assignment always evaluates to true.  It's a common mistake.

Comment: Definitely a good way to solve the problem. The OP, as a beginner of cpp, should pay no attention to *lvalue* or *rvalue*. Just focus on the code itself is best.